# RegExp for matching usernames: min 3 chars, max 20 chars, optional underscore in between chars

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm attempting to match roblox usernames (which follow these guidelines):

- Minimum of 3 characters
- Maximum of 20 characters
- Maximum of 1 underscore
- Underscore may not be at the beginning or end of the username

I am running on node.js version 10.12.0.

My current RegExp is:
`/^([a-z0-9])(\w)+([a-z0-9])$/i`, but this does not account for the limit of 1 underscore.

[image: List of some unit tests on regex101.com]

Comment: Regular expressions are bad at counting. Did you consider solving this requirement in JavaScript instead?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: You don't really need to *count* for the condition to only have one underscore. It is completely achievable with negated character classes and anchors.

Comment: He might have referred to the character limitation, where one *may* achieve a performance improvement by checking the string with `.length` in JavaScript.

Comment: While this problem can be solved by a single regex, the code is harder to understand. At least, *when a positive lookahead is required to simulate matching two regexes simultaneously* `str.match(/^(?=regex1$)regex2$/)`, *just use two regexes* `str.match(/^regex1$/) && str.match(/^regex2$/)`.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it is achievable, but that is not my point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?=^[^_]+_?[^_]+$)\w{3,20}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pPrhNo/4/) (there are newline characters for demo purposes)

---

Broken down this is

```
^         # start of the string
(?=
    ^     # start of the string
    [^_]+ # not an underscore, at least once
    _?    # an underscore
    [^_]+ # not an underscore, at least once
    $     # end of the string
 )
\w{3,20}  # 3-20 alphanumerical characters
$         # end
```

---

The question has received quite some attention so I felt to add a non-regex version as well:

```js
let usernames = ['gt_c', 'gt', 'g_t_c', 'gtc_', 'OnlyTwentyCharacters', 'poppy_harlow'];

let alphanumeric = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_']);

function isValidUsername(user) {
    /* non-regex version */
    // length
    if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 20)
        return false;

    // not allowed to start/end with underscore
    if (user.startsWith('_') || user.endsWith('_'))
        return false;
        
    // max one underscore
    var underscores = 0;
    for (var c of user) {
        if (c == '_') underscores++;
        if (!alphanumeric.has(c))
            return false;
    }

    if (underscores > 1)
        return false;
        
    // if none of these returned false, it's probably ok
    return true;
}

function isValidUsernameRegex(user) {
    /* regex version */
    if (user.match(/^(?=^[^_]+_?[^_]+$)\w{3,20}$/))
        return true;
    return false;
}

usernames.forEach(function(username) {
    console.log(username + " = " + isValidUsername(username));
});
```

I personally think the regex version is shorter and cleaner but it's up to you to decide. Especially the alphanumeric part requires either some comparisons or a regex. With the latter in mind, you could use a regex version altogether.

Comment: Nice short solution, though I'm not sure OP's rules would allow other special characters than underscore, such as dash or non-ASCII.

Comment: This regex does not account for usernames with no underscore.

Comment: @JamieClark: Now it does.

Answer (score 4):

Could be like this:

```
^(?=^\w{3,20}$)[a-z0-9]+_?[a-z0-9]+$
|     |            |    |     | End with any alphanumeric
|     |            |    | 
|     |            |   Optional underscore in middle
|     |            |    
|     |      Start with any alphanumeric
|     |
|  Any accepted chars
|  between 3 and 20 chars.
|
Start of string
```

The positive lookahead ensures the length will be of minimum 3 chars and maximum 20, and we check for an optional underscore in between one or more characters.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/4c3xkf/4) – I have [added unit testing](https://regex101.com/r/4c3xkf/4/tests) similar to yours as well.

---

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using `JS functions` along with `regex` this is how i will do.

In matches i included all the matching strings by neglecting the `_` condition and in final i am checking for the `_` condition.

```js
let str = `_vila
v_v
v__v
v_v
vvvvvv_
12345678912345678912
12345678912345678912123456`


let matches = str.match(/^[a-z0-9]\w{1,18}[a-z0-9]$/gm)

let final = matches.map(e=> (e.split('_').length < 3 ? ({value:e,match:true}) : ({value:e,match:false})))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant: `/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|_(?!.*_)){1,18}[a-z0-9]$/i`